# Report Builder TFS: Filter on todays date only

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, reportbuilder3.0

I am currently trying to build a report that pulls all the created bugs today into a report. The fields I am using are 'Work Item.Created Date' and 'Work Item Count'. What I am getting information back. The problem is I can't seem to get the report to only show items for today. I have set a filter of:

Expression: [Created_Date] as Text (What I can not change)

Operator: =

Value: =Today()

When I run this I get the following error:

The processing of FilterExpression for the dataset ‘DataSet1’ cannot be performed. Cannot compare data of types System.String and System.DateTime. Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression. (rsComparisonTypeError)

I have tried using the following as the Vale entry:

`=Today().Parse("12/04/2009").ToString()`

I don't get an error but I am not 100% sure if it is right, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of bugs then you should connect to the Data Warehouse (tfs_warehouse) rather than the Cube (tfs_analysis) and pull a list from the WorkItems table.

This should be easyer to query. Additionally I do not believe that "today()" is processed as you expect. You need to get todays date and pass it in rather than use "today()".